# JSON JAVA client to connect server and receive data

Tags: java, java-me

I have a sinatra server, I need the client in java that receive data using json from sinatra. I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Jersey client](http://codedependents.com/2009/04/20/rest-calls-and-json-results-in-java/) to get JSON data from server. Use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to [convert it from JSON to your objects](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples).

Comment: Ahhh, it probably wont work under javaME/BDJ. You never mentioned BDJ and I just now realized you have a tag `java-me`.