# sinatra ruby in question

Tags: ruby, sinatra

How to do that I have got resource in sinatra
http://localhost:port/resource.json ??

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Please clarify.

Comment: Hiya, You will have to give us more detail if we are going to be able to answer your question. Also - you are referencing a local URL only visible to you.

Comment: I don't understand your question. I don't understand the title of the question either. Also isn't this a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5233175/?

Answer (score 2):

Install the json gem:

> sudo gem install json

then just

```
require 'json'
get '/resource.json' do
  content_type :json
  { :name => 'Michal', :location => 'unknown' }.to_json
end
```

Comment: +1 for understanding the question and for the JSON gem, which is **awesome**! :D

Comment: I still don't know what the question is... This is like Stackoverflow Jeopardy...